# Why does this code take 8 minutes to finish?

Tags: ruby

This is a (pretty bad) solution to one of the project Euler problems. The problem was to find the 10_001st prime number. The code below does it, but it takes 8 minutes to run. Can you explain why that is the case and how to optimize it?

```
primes = []
number = 2.0

until primes[10000] != nil
  if (2..(number - 1)).any? do |n|
    number % n == 0
  end == false
    primes << number
  end
  number = number + 1.0
end

puts primes[10000]
```

Comment: `if enumeration.any?{} == false` => `if enumeration.none?{}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some simple optimizations to prime finding:

- Start by pushing 2 onto your primes list, and start by checking if 3 is a prime. (This eliminates needing to write special case code for the numbers 0 to 2)
- You only have to check numbers that are odd for prime candidacy. (Or, if you start by adding 2/3/5 and checking 7, you only need to check numbers that are 1 or 5 after doing % 6. Or... You get the idea)
- You only have to see if your current candidate `x` is divisible by factors up to sqrt(`x`)—because any factor above `sqrt(x)` divides x into a number below `sqrt(x)`, and you've already checked all of those.
- You only have to check numbers in your prime list, instead of all numbers, for divisors of `x` - since all composite numbers are divisible by primes. For example, 81 is 9*9 - but 9*9 is 3*3*9, 9 being composite, so you'll discover it's a prime when you check it against 3. Therefore you never need to test if 9 is a factor, and so on for every composite factor.

There are very optimized, sped up prime finding functions (see the [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) for a start), but these are the common optimizations that are easy to come up with.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have to check if the number divides with all previous numbers? Check only with the smaller primes you already discovered. Also, why using floats where integers are perfectly fine?

**EDIT:**

Some possible changes (not best algorithm, can be improved):

```
primes = [2, 3, 5]
num = 7

until primes[10000]
  is_prime = true
  i = 0
  sqrtnum = Math.sqrt(num).ceil
  while (n=primes[i+=1]) <= sqrtnum
    if num % n == 0
      is_prime = false
      break
    end
  end
  if is_prime
    primes << num
  end
  num += 2
end

puts primes[10000]
```

On my computer (for 1000 primes):

```
 Yours:
real    0m3.300s
user    0m3.284s
sys     0m0.000s

 Mine:
real    0m0.045s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Comment: Not sure checking only with the smaller primes you already discovered would be sufficient

Comment: DavidC: It would. Think about it: if the number is not divisible by any primes smaller than itself, it is also not divisible by any product of two or more of these primes. An additional implication of this, is that you only need to check primes no larger than a square root of the number being checked.